# How to make flask application run every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have this application that works how I want to but now I want it to grab live data from some virtual machines every 5 minutes. In the code below I have it set to renew every ten seconds just to see if it works but nothing is happening. I am using time.sleep. What else am I missing?

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from testapi import grab_cpu

app = Flask(__name__)

starttime = time.time()
while True:

    machines =["build05", "build06", "build07","build08", "build09", "build10", "build11", "build12","build14","build15", "winbuild10","winbuild11", "winbuild12", "winbuild13", "wbuild14", "wbuild15", "winbuild16", "winbuild17", "winbuild18"] 

    cpu_percentage =[grab_cpu("build05"), grab_cpu("build06"),grab_cpu("build07"),  
            grab_cpu("build08"), grab_cpu("build09"), grab_cpu("build10"), grab_cpu("build11"), grab_cpu("build12"), grab_cpu("build13"), grab_cpu("build14"), grab_cpu("build15"), grab_cpu("winbuild10"), grab_cpu("winbuild11"), grab_cpu("winbuild12"), grab_cpu("winbuild14"), grab_cpu("winbuild15"), grab_cpu("winbuild16"), grab_cpu("winbuild17"), grab_cpu("winbuild18")] 

    @app.route("/")  # this sets the route to this page
    def home():
        return render_template('testdoc.html', len = len(machines), machines = machines, cpu_percentage = cpu_percentage)

    app.run(use_reloader = True, debug = True) 
    time.sleep(10.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10.0))
```

Edit (this is an update with the suggestions, it's still not working as i'd like):
Edit 2 more info: I have one file with a function, grab_cpu, that does an api call to a vm and returns the percentage of usage. I have another file called test doc.html which just displays the html. From these responses i'm guessing I need to use some javascript and something with sockets. Can someone please drop a link to point me in the right direction?

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from testapi import grab_cpu

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")  # this sets the route to this page
def home():
    starttime = time.time()

    while True:
        machines =["build05", "build06", "build07","build08", "build09", "build10", "build11", "build12","build14","build15", "winbuild10","winbuild11", "winbuild12", "winbuild13", "wbuild14", "wbuild15", "winbuild16", "winbuild17", "winbuild18"] 

        cpu_percentage =[grab_cpu("build05"), grab_cpu("build06"),grab_cpu("build07"),  
            grab_cpu("build08"), grab_cpu("build09"), grab_cpu("build10"), grab_cpu("build11"), grab_cpu("build12"), grab_cpu("build13"), grab_cpu("build14"), grab_cpu("build15"), grab_cpu("winbuild10"), grab_cpu("winbuild11"), grab_cpu("winbuild12"), grab_cpu("winbuild14"), grab_cpu("winbuild15"), grab_cpu("winbuild16"), grab_cpu("winbuild17"), grab_cpu("winbuild18")] 
        return render_template('testdoc.html', len = len(machines), machines = machines, cpu_percentage = cpu_percentage)
        time.sleep(10.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10.0))
app.run(use_reloader = True, debug = True)
```

Here is the page:
[image: picture of site]

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do this. Move your queries inside the `home` route and move it behind a redis or some similar caching system to keep from running that expensive operation multiple times.

Comment: I can't see that you are using any recognised design pattern.  1. Have a controller process hat can call a restful API route in flask app that updates a cache (e.g. redis) 2. your home route displays data by getting data from cache using render_template. 3. if you want your client browser to refresh page on a different frequency use a bit of JS with `setinterval()` that reloads page

Comment: @RobRaymond I don't think I am. I just learned flask two days ago. Still learning. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @AdamSmith Do you mean move my variables? Which operation is expensive? I assume calling grab_cpu() each time is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend against using Flask to handle the scheduling. The intended flow for Flask requests is:

1. Receive an HTTP request from the browser
2. Generate a response as quickly as possible (ideally in a few milliseconds, but almost always less than a few seconds)
3. Return the response to the browser

The intention of the code above seems to be to use Flask to *push* updates down to the browser, but Flask can only respond to incoming requests, not force the browser to change.

For the use case you're describing, a simpler solution would be to handle the refresh logic in the browser.

For a very rudimentary example, put this into your `testdoc.html` template:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 10 * 1000);
</script>
```

That will reload the page every 10 seconds, which will generate a new request to your Flask server and display updated information in your browser.

If you want to get fancier and avoid reloading the entire page, you can use JavaScript [XmlHttpRequests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) or the more modern [Fetch API](https://alligator.io/js/fetch-api/) to update specific elements of the page asynchronously.

Also, here's a suggested simplification of the Python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from testapi import grab_cpu

app = Flask(__name__)

build_machines = list(map(lambda i: 'build%02d' % i, range(5, 16)))
win_build_machines = list(map(lambda i: 'winbuild%02d' % i, range(10, 19)))
machines = build_machines + win_build_machines

# Handle HTTP GET requests to / route
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def home():
        cpu_percentage = list(map(lambda b: grab_cpu(b), machines))
        return render_template('testdoc.html', len = len(machines), machines = machines, cpu_percentage = cpu_percentage)

app.run(use_reloader = True, debug = True)
```

Comment: I ended up using another method besides flask to get my intended result but I appreciate this explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs some work, Flask views are not meant to be declared inside a loop. I would suggest the following:

1. Remove the Flask view from inside the while loop.
2. Declare the server outside the loop too.
3. Write your code inside a function.
4. Run the while loop just calling the function to grab the information from your sources.

Based on what I think is just an example made on the run, I will also make some assumptions about your requirement:

- This is not exactly your code.
- Your code works perfectly, but this implementation is lacking.
- Your project has some level of complexity.
- You need to show this data somewhere else.

Base on these (and perhaps additional conditions), I would say you have two ways to achieve in an effective way what you need:

1. (Not recommended) Create a Cron Job and run everything in a dedicated script.
2. (My favorite) Encapsulate the logic of your script inside a Flask API call, a method, or a function, and declare it as a Celery task, scheduled to run every 5 seconds, updating your database, and use a view with some JS reactivity to show the data in realtime.

Comment: I am confused why you do not believe this is my code...

Comment: The basic mistakes in the Python syntax made me think this was not your production-ready code @ColorfulCodes